# Which disk monitor tool can get the health status of logical drives with their corresponding physical drivers

Tags: diskmanagement

Preivously I always used the hdsentinel tool to get the health status of physical drives, but it still cannot get the correct mapping relationship between the upper logical and physical drives ......
So now I want to look for another alternative disk monitor tool like hdssentinel, which but also can get the correct mapping relationship between the logical and physical drivers.

https://www.hdsentinel.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14482